# osmscout on BQ Aquaris E4.5

Tags: ubuntu-touch, downloads, phone

When I downloaded a map (Austria) an error occured and now I have no maps   available.

I uninstalled the app, but the mistake is still alive.

What to do now?

Comment: Reset the phone to default factory settings is the fastest way of getting rid of this...  (not the most elegant, so just a comment)

Answer (score 0):

After deinstalling the app, try taking a look to /home/phablet/.cache and /home/phablet/.local and search for any osmscout contents and delete them manually.

Then reinstall the app and report if this had success.

Nevertheless, may you should rise a bug against osmscout app and provide more information about the error...

Answer (score 0):

If there is a lock file in /home/phablet/.config/osmscout.fransschreuder, delete it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/555395)

Comment: I had a problem and the program said I had no maps. It didn't allow make click on the keys. When I deleted a file in /home/phablet/.config/osmscout.fransschreuder I had the map. I don't understand why this is not an answer :)

Comment: If this is not an answer it could be removed. I think this would be the best way to solve it.

Comment: @Pilot6 This looks like a valid attempt to answer the question to me.

Comment: @Seth I agree. It is a poor answer, but a valid one.

Comment: It worked for me (although I did not read well and deleted all the home/phablet/.config/osmscout.fransschreuder folder).